# error: request for member ‘data’ in ‘* root’, which is of pointer type ‘nodeBST*’

Tags: c++11, pointers, binary-search-tree, pointer-to-member, pointer-to-pointer

error: request for member ‘data’ in ‘* root’, which is of pointer type ‘nodeBST*’

I just used the pointer to pointer to dereference the data members.Am I following the wrong approach ??

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
class nodeBST
{
    int data;
    nodeBST *leftChild;
    nodeBST *rightChild;
    void insertNode(nodeBST **root , int data);
    nodeBST* getNewnodeBST(int data);
    void searchnodeBST(nodeBST **root , int data);
};
nodeBST* nodeBST::getNewnodeBST(int data)
{
      nodeBST* temp = new nodeBST();
      temp->data = data;
      temp->leftChild = temp->rightChild = NULL;
      return temp;
}
void nodeBST::insertNode(nodeBST **root , int data)
{
  if(*root == NULL)*root = getNewnodeBST(data);
  else if(data <= *root->data)*root->leftChild = insertNode(*root->leftChild , data);//error started from here
  else *root->rightChild = insertNode(*root->rightChild , data);
}
void nodeBST::searchnodeBST(nodeBST **root , int data)
{
    if(*root == NULL)return false;
    else if(*root->data == data)return true;
    else if(data <= *root->data) return searchnodeBST(*root->leftChild,data);
    else return searchnodeBST(*root->rightChild,data);
}
int main()
{
    nodeBST *root = NULL;
    nodeBST::insertNode(&root , 12);
    nodeBST::insertNode(&root , 125);
    nodeBST::insertNode(&root , 13);
    nodeBST::insertNode(&root , 188);
}
```

Comment: The problem you're having is one of [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). The structure member access operator `->` has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`. Some extra parentheses will solve it.

Comment: error: no matching function for call to ‘nodeBST::insertNode(nodeBST*&, int&)’
https://paste.ofcode.org/4LZNJR3CG2UWVv9LZnqmhu

Comment: `insertNode` is declared to return `void`, yet you are trying to assign its (non-existent) return value to various variables. You are probably looking for `insertNode(&((*root)->leftChild) , data)`

Comment: https://paste.ofcode.org/ffZjETeJrcaJVkQDRdkjL7
still couldnt find it :
error: request for member ‘insertNode’ in ‘bst’, which is of pointer type ‘nodeBST*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)|